# After installing pandas-profiling, I tried to import it and ran into a problem

Tags: python-3.x, valueerror, pandas-profiling

I installed pandas-profiling using pip command and successfully installed it.
But, when importing it,

```
from pandas_profiling import ProfileReport
```

I ran into the problem,

```
ValueError: bad marshal data (unknown type code)
```